# move div to coordinate on svg map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I currently have a map svg on my page

```
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="worldHigh.svg" width="1060" height="800">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
```

Not when I light op certain path id's on the map I need to be able to move a div to that place on the map.

I currently have the following function that returns the x and y coordinates.

```
    function getPosition(element) {
        segments = element.pathSegList;
        return { x: segments.getItem(0).x, y: segments.getItem(0).y };
    }
```

Now the problem Im facing is finding the coordinates relative to the position on the screen so I can move a div there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options that I can see:

1 - You can get the object tag offset with jQuery (`$("object").offset()`) and use its 'left' and 'top' attributes to find out the object position on the screen. The div positions is (left + x, top + y).

2 - You can wrap your object inside a div, set the div position as relative, and move the desired div to inside wrapping div setting x and y as its position.